# Is there an action of $S_2$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that has exactly two orbits?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am studying for an algebra midterm and I am trying to solve the following problem: Is there an action of $S_2$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that has exactly two orbits?

So far what I have been thinking is that I know that the order of an orbit must divide the order of the group acting on the set by the orbit-stabilizer theorem. This means that, in this case, each orbit must have order $1$ or $2$. However, because the orbits are equivalence classes, they partition $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so the distinct orbits must have in total $5$ elements but if there are two orbits then they have a total of $2$ different elements since each has order $1$. If there are exactly two orbits, then they both must have order $1$. I don't see though how an orbit couldn't have order $2$, because $O_x = \{gx | g \in S_2\}$ and there are two elements in $S_2$.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: I agree up to "they partition $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$", but after that I don't understand what you are trying to say. Each orbit has either $1$ or $2$ elements, so two orbits of the action have, in total, at most $2+2=4$ elements. That means they cannot exhaust your set, so you are done.

Comment: I suppose what's most confusing me is the last part. How can each orbit not have exactly two elements if O(x) is the product of x with the two elements from $S_2$ which has two elements?

Comment: The action can be trivial. Say you send the nontrivial element of $S_2$ to the permutation $(1,2)(3,4)(5)$. Then the orbits are $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$, and $\{5\}$. What exactly is the problem with the orbit having just one element? Note that the identity of $S_2$ **always** leaves elements fixed; otherwise you don’t have an action. And remember that $gx = hx$ does **not** imply $g=h$, even if it holds for all $x\in X$.

Comment: One of the orbits has to be of cardinality 3. And that contradicts orbit stabilizer.

Comment: I mean, you could have the trivial action: just let $gx=x$ for all $g\in S_2$ and all $x\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. This is a perfectly good action, and all orbits have length $1$. But this confusion is a confusion about the basics of group actions, not about this particular problem!

Comment: @justanothermathstudent: one of the orbits would have size *at least* $3$....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh yes. But that's also a problem

Comment: @justanothermathstudent: I’m not saying it isn’t; just that your assertion, if you are going to by contradiction, is not *quite* accurate. It’s not that one orbit would necessarily have length exactly three. So your argument, as you gave it, would be incomplete.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I was wrong at the first place.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What do you mean by sending the nontrivial element of $S_2$ to $(1,2)(3,4)(5)$? Do you mean, if we call that nontrivial element $g$ then $gx = (1,2)(3,4)(5)x$?

Comment: I mean that $S_2$ has two elements. The identity must fix everything in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so I just need to tell you what the other element does. The other element acts on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ as a permutation on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and that permutation must have order dividing $2$. So when I say I map it to $(1,2)(3,4)(5)$, I mean that the action is $g1=2$, $g2=1$, $g3=4$, $g4=3$, and $g5=5$. An action of $G$ on $X$ is equivalent to a group homomorphism from $G$ to $S_X$, so I gave you the image in $S_{\{1,2,3,4,5\}}$. If you are confused by this, you **really** need to review group actions.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Yes, I'll definitely review group actions. So what you're saying is that one of the elements of the group $S$ acting on $X$ can just leave some element of $X$ fixed, and so not all the orbits need to have the same order?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, *<<..I mean that $S_2$ has two elements. The identity must fix everything in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$...>>*: couldn't this alone give the answer to the OP? By Burnside Lemma, we have that the number of orbits is: $|\mathcal{O}|=\frac{1}{2}(5+...) \ne 2$?

Comment: @Luca: Burnside's Lemma is an advanced application of the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem. Given that the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem already gives you all you need, there is no need to bring out the atomic bomb in order to swat the fly.

Comment: @SpencerGibson: There is *never* a requirement that all orbits of an element have the same size. Or all orbits of a group have the same size.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

You are on the right track, I think. Let's clarify things.

If $G$ is a group acting on a set $X$ and $x\in X$ then there is a bijection (even $G$-isomorphism) between the orbit $Gx$ and the collection of all cosets $G/G_x$ where $G_x$ is the stabilizer subgroup for $x$. This is also known as [the orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside's_lemma). In particular this shows that in the finite case $|Gx|$ divides $|G|$, as a consequence of Lagrange's theorem.

And so in our case $G=S_2$ (which has exactly $2$ elements) it means that any orbit (of any action on any set) has either $1$ or $2$ elements. The case when an orbit has one element is trivial: $S_2$ acting on any set $Y$ via $(g,y)\mapsto y$. The case when an orbit has two elements is for example when $S_2$ acts on itself (or disjoint union of itselves) via $(g,h)\mapsto gh$.

And since the set $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ has $5$ elements then it has to have at least $3$ orbits regardless of how $S_2$ acts on it. That's because orbits form a partition of any set.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the orbits of an action of a group $G$ of order $2$ on a set $S$ consist of a maximum of $2$ elements (Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem: for every $s \in S$, $|O(s)||Stab(s)|=|G|=2$, thence $|O(s)| \le 2$). If $|S|=5$, being $S$ partitioned into action's orbits, there must be at least $3$ orbits. This holds in general, for any action of any group of order $2$ on any set of cardinality $5$, and this would suffice for your problem.

A different matter is if we want "to see" this all in action for a specific group (say $S_2$), a specific set (say $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$) and a specific action of the former on the latter. To this aim, we need to remind that an action of $S_2$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is equivalent to a homomorphism from $S_2$ to $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1,2,3,4,5\})=S_5$. Now, any map $\varphi \colon S_2=\{\iota_{S_2},(12)\} \longrightarrow S_5$, defined by $\varphi(\iota_{S_2})=\iota_{S_5}$ and $\varphi((12))=\alpha$, *where $\alpha$ is an element of order $2$ of $S_5$*, is a homomorphism from $S_2$ to $S_5$. As an example, let's take the "most natural" such a $\varphi$, namely the one featured by $\varphi((12))=(12) \in S_5$; then, the orbit of *this* action by the point $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is the set

$$O(i)=\{\varphi(\sigma)(i), \sigma \in S_2\}=\{i\} \cup \{(12)(i)\} \tag 1$$

Deploying $(1)$, we get:

$$O(1)=\{1,2\}, \quad O(2)=\{2,1\}=O(1), \quad O(3)=\{3\}, \quad O(4)=\{4\}, \quad O(5)=\{5\}$$

so, one orbit of $2$ elements and three orbits of $1$ element each.

If, instead, we take $\varphi((12))=(12)(34)$, yet another order $2$ element of $S_5$, then this other action has orbits

$$O(i)=\{\varphi(\sigma)(i), \sigma \in S_2\}=\{i\} \cup \{(12)(34)(i)\} \tag 2$$

Deploying $(2)$, we get:

$$O(1)=\{1,2\}, \quad O(2)=\{2,1\}=O(1), \quad O(3)=\{3,4\}, \quad O(4)=\{4,3\}=O(3), \quad O(5)=\{5\}$$

so, this time we have two orbits of $2$ elements each and one orbit of $1$ element.

Needless to say that both these particular cases comply with the general result gotten by the O.S.T. for all the actions of groups of order $2$ on sets of cardinality $5$, namely that at least $3$ orbits must be there.